# Latency in deployment of Smart Contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

My contract is not getting deployed. Though it complied successfully and works fine in Remix editor but when I am trying to deploy it on Rinkeby Test Network via infura it is not getting deployed.
Here is my code for deployment :

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const Register = require('../Ethereum/build/Register_Manufacturer.json');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  'lumber ill danger ride rare brisk trick clarify front rely vacant fan',
  'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/39729526ed3846adbe840d6d87dd13c3'
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
  console.log(Register.bytecode);
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  console.log('Address of account', accounts[0]);

  const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(Register.interface))
    .deploy({ data: Register.bytecode })
    .send({ gas: '6700000', gasPrice: '10000000000', from: accounts[0] });

  console.log('Contract deployed at', result.options.address);
};
deploy();
```

Comment: Can you include in your question any logs / error messages?

Comment: No error was returned..... it was just due to some traffic on the rinkeby network I guess, there are a lot of issues related to gas while deploying such things, later I tried again it got deployed. But still few of the transactions gets rejected due to this not enough gas problem. It will be great if you help me in this regard.